# Function with missing disabled variable is running

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I added `Disabled("MYVAR")` to my function as per documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function#other-methods). Then I thought that removing the app setting MYVAR would default the disable to true, to make it NOT run. But it seems to default to false so missing variables will make the Azure Function run anyways? Does that make sense? Should it not default to true and stop the function if the variable is missing? [The default of a boolean is false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values), but here it should be true?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change the default value of a boolean in some cases? This would be very confusing.

As you say: removing `MYVAR` will set it to `false`. And `Disabled == false` is enabled. 
Your function is enabled now. IMHO, that's perfectly expected behavior.